# How can i calculate and show how much time left and will take to download each file?

Tags: c#

```
public void GetAllImages()
        {

            // Bing Image Result for Cat, First Page
            string url = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&go=&form=QB&qs=n";


            // For speed of dev, I use a WebClient
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string html = client.DownloadString(url);

            // Load the Html into the agility pack
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            // Now, using LINQ to get all Images
            /*List<HtmlNode> imageNodes = null;
            imageNodes = (from HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
                          where node.Name == "img"
                          && node.Attributes["class"] != null
                          && node.Attributes["class"].Value.StartsWith("sg_t")
                          select node).ToList();*/

           var imageLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
    .Where(n => n.Attributes["class"].Value == "sg_t")
    .Select(n => HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(n.Attributes["src"].Value)["amp;url"]).ToList();





            foreach (string node in imageLinks)
            {
                y++;
                //Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
                richTextBox1.Text += node + Environment.NewLine;
                Image t = DownloadImage(node);
                t.Save(@"d:\test\" + y.ToString("D6" + ".jpg"));

            }


        }


        public Image DownloadImage(string _URL)
        {
            Image _tmpImage = null;

            try
            {
                // Open a connection
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest _HttpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_URL);

                _HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

                // You can also specify additional header values like the user agent or the referer: (Optional)
                //_HttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
                //_HttpWebRequest.Referer = "http://www.google.com/";

                // set timeout for 20 seconds (Optional)
                _HttpWebRequest.Timeout = 60000;

                // Request response:
                System.Net.WebResponse _WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                // Open data stream:
                System.IO.Stream _WebStream = _WebResponse.GetResponseStream();

                // convert webstream to image
                _tmpImage = Image.FromStream(_WebStream);

                // Cleanup
                _WebResponse.Close();
                _WebResponse.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception _Exception)
            {
                // Error
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
                return null;
            }

            return _tmpImage;
        }
```

For now just to use the richTextBox1 i have to show in it the time that left for the download and how long the download will take.

And is there any faster way to download files or httprequest is good enough ?

Comment: You title does not seem to match the question, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could download them in parallel:

Parallel.ForEach(imageLinks, node => 
{
    Image t = DownloadImage(node);
    lock(y)
    {
        t.Save(@"d:\test\" + (y++).ToString("D6" + ".jpg"));
    }
}

Or if you are downloading them inside an ASP.NET app, you could better download them from the client via ajax calls.

Comment: Joshua Drake, The question inside is a sub question the main question is the title how to calculate how much time left and how much time it will take. The question in the end is another question sub question.